# Can't create a WebAssembly module out of an MDL file using EMCC

Tags: webassembly, emcc

I am trying to create a WebAssembly module out of an MDL file. I am following this tutorial:

```
https://github.com/climateinteractive/SDEverywhere/tree/main/examples/hello-world
```

The problem is that when I run the following command

```
npm run dev
```

I get this error:

```
emcc: error: EXPORT_ES6 and ENVIRONMENT=*node* requires USE_ES6_IMPORT_META to be set
```

Therefore I tried to set the value of USE_ES6_IMPORT_META to 0 (then to 1), but still doesn't work.